# User delete assertion

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make an assertion while deleting a user. The problem is that after I delete user I am trying to 'FindElement' with his name but while he's not longer available there occurs exception and program stop running. Is there any solution or should I try other assertion?

Comment: use try and catch block.

Comment: You can use findElement and get the false result and use the `Assert.assertFalse(condition)` for get the right condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `FindElement` you can simply use `FindElements`.
It returns list of web elements.
In case the element is no longer presented you will get an empty list.
So you can simly check the size of list returned by the `FindElements` method without dealing with trying the exceptions.
So you should use something like:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("your_xpath_locator")).Count > 0
```

Comment: Wouldn't it take more time if user is deleted ? Since it will search for user, I believe having try and catch could solve this problem little bit much faster but yeah if you use findElements inside try you would be in same situation

Comment: No, `FindElements` and `FindElement` returning their returns immediately unless you are changing the implicit wait that is not recommended  itself ;)

Comment: I am FindingElements inside bool method and while I am trying to make a condition if FoundElements < 0; return True then there is an error: "ErrorCS0019 Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>' and 'int'"

Comment: See my updated answer. First of all you should check the length of returned list and it is performed by Count method in C#. Second you should check if the size is 0 or greater than 0. It will never be a negative amount.

Comment: I made it a little bit differently than you showed but it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great! I'm happy I could help you :)